# gulp записать в выходной html дату его создания

Tags: gulp

ну вот таск мой один к примеру...
как в конец файла записать примерно так`/*31.05.2017 20:47:16*/`
?

```
            gulp.task('js', function() {
            gulp.src([
                        'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',                
                        'src/c-javascripts/owl.carousel.min.js',
                        'src/c-javascripts/jqstart.js',
                        'src/c-javascripts/**.js',
                        'src/c-javascripts/jqend.js'
                ]) // файлы, которые обрабатываем
                .pipe(concat('nano.js')) // склеиваем все JS
                //.pipe(uglify()) // получившуюся "портянку" минифицируем 
                .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/')) // результат пишем по указанному адресу
                .pipe(gulp.dest('C:/domains/mysite/js/')) // дубль в сервак
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для имени файлика можно добавить в файл кусок кода:

```
function getDateTime() {
        var now     = new Date(); 
        var year    = now.getFullYear();
        var month   = now.getMonth()+1; 
        var day     = now.getDate();
        var hour    = now.getHours();
        var minute  = now.getMinutes();
        var second  = now.getSeconds(); 
        if(month.toString().length == 1) { var month = '0'+month; }
        if(day.toString().length == 1) { var day = '0'+day; }   
        if(hour.toString().length == 1) { var hour = '0'+hour; }
        if(minute.toString().length == 1) { var minute = '0'+minute; }
        if(second.toString().length == 1) { var second = '0'+second; }   
        var dateTime = year+'-'+month+'-'+day+'T'+hour+':'+minute+':'+second;   
        return dateTime;
    }
```

И вызвать:

```
.pipe(concat('nano.js_' + getDateTime()))
```

---

А еще можно дописать внутрь файла с помощью **gulp-insert**.

Надо добавить еще немного кода:

```
var insert = require('gulp-insert');
....
....
.pipe(insert.append('hello_world '  + getDateTime()))
```

Comment: спасибо, отлично, а можно чтоб эту дату в div как-то с document.getElementById("datetime") записывать?

Comment: имею ввиду в выходном файле , если это html

Comment: gulp-dom что-то не подключается